# get Connection Strength in Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am working on a phonegap application. I want to sync the data into application from the server, but it needs's a good connection strength.So I need to find out connection strength of the connection.

There are lots of documentation of internet to find connection type using phonegap, but I can't find any help regarding connection strength

Is there any way to find the connection strength in phonegap, I don't want to use any native platform code cause it will bw working on many platforms, So is there any way to find out the connection(2g, 3g, 4g, wifi etc...) strength in phonegap????

Comment: hey, you are asking to acquire strength of network not the status right? I mean you're not asking to detect type of the connection because it's already available on Phonegap API Document.

Comment: @gokhanakkurt Yes I need to get strength of connection, If it is good then I will perform some network operation, Otherwise displays a error message of slow connection.

Comment: Phonegap API does not provide any plugin for this purpose. You should write your own plugin that interacts with JavaScript code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no any standard way find out connection strength in `android` too, So I just use a `javascript` code to get the speed of internet connection, There is no issue with any platform `android`, `ios` or `windows phone 8` etc, No need to develop a separate plugin for each platform.

Just use the following `scripts` :

```js
var downloadSize = 244736;
var imageAddr = "http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5035/5802797131_a729dac808_b.jpg" + "?n=" + Math.random();
var startTime, endTime = 0;
var download = new Image();
download.onload = function () {
    endTime = ( new Date() ).getTime();
    showResults( startTime, endTime, imageAddr, downloadSize );
};

startTime = ( new Date() ).getTime();
download.src = imageAddr;

function isConnected() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var file = "http://api.androidhive.info/music/images/adele.png";
    var r = Math.round( Math.random() * 10000 );
    xhr.open( 'HEAD', file + "?subins=" + r, false );
    try {
        xhr.send();
        if ( xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 304 ) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch ( e ) {
        return false;
    }
};

function showResults( startTime, endTime, imageAddr, downloadSize ) {
    if ( isConnected() ) {
        var duration = ( endTime - startTime ) / 1000; //Math.round()
        var bitsLoaded = downloadSize * 8;
        var speedBps = Number( ( bitsLoaded / duration ).toFixed( 2 ) );
        var speedKbps = Number( ( speedBps / 1024 ).toFixed( 2 ) );
        var finalSpeed = ( speedKbps / 10 );

        if ( finalSpeed < 40 ) {
            // Slow Internet

        } else if ( finalSpeed >= 40 && finalSpeed < 80 ) {
            // Avg Internet

        } else if ( finalSpeed >= 80 ) {
            // Fast Internet
        }
    } else {
        //No intenet
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So far I know you have to write a custom plugin and deal with the native code. There isn't any direct way to get the signal strength till now in phonegap.